# Can't load font-awesome with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, font-awesome

Trying to load font-awesome with webpack gives me this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3
Module parse failed: ...\node_modules\font-awesome\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3 Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

I'm trying to import font-awesome in a React component like this:

```
import "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

Here's what my webpack.config.js looks like. I wanted to load font-awesome and related assets separately from everything else, namely because I'm already loading SVGs with babel, but didn't want to do that with font-awesome.

```
{
    test: /\.scss/,
    loader: ExtractPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass")
},
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: "babel!svg-react",
    exclude: /node_modules/
},
{
    test: /\.ttf$/,
    loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=[name].[ext]",
    exclude: /node_modules/
},
{
    test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=[name].[ext]",
    exclude: /node_modules/
},
{
    test: /\.(otf|eot|png|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
    loader: "url?limit=10000",
    include: "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts"
}
```

I've tried doing the regex like this too and it didn't work:

```
{ test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000" }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To properly load font-awesome fonts, you need to configure loaders in your webpack.config.js to use url-loader and file-loader. Example:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // the url-loader uses DataUrls. 
      // the file-loader emits files. 
      { 
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

to do this, you'll need to npm install font-awesome-sass-loader `npm i font-awesome-sass-loader`
You'll also need url-loader `npm i url-loader`
and file-loader `npm i file-loader`

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me after trying many examples:

```
  { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
  { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
```

and for sure fontawsome need to be imported in your main file

```
  import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

also don't forget to install the loader

```
  npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: Can't you just do it in one line with `(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)`?

Answer (score 3):

Try loading your `.eot` files with the `file-loader` instead of `url-loader`.

**Example**:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?|otf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
            loaders: ['file']
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why should we use the `file-loader` instead of `url-loader`?

Comment: @crx4 see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49080007/1684480